# Activity always active

Tags: android, android-activity

I´m making an Android App with a Google Map. This app must alert you when you are locate out of the route in the map. But, when the mobil is in standby, the app is sleeping. How can I create an app with the activity on active during the route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a service that runs in the background. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html